# Login to the API manager through Eclipse Developer Tools

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

I'm unable to connect to the API Manager when using Developer Tools for WSO2. I'm following the instructions on this [**page**](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Pass+a+Custom+Authorization+Token+to+the+Backend). When I try to log in to the publisher I get this error

[image: Connection error]

When I try connecting to the publisher through port 9443 I get this error.

[image]

The environment I'm running is APIM 2.1.0 with the IDS 5.3.0 as key manager. I'm using a clustered environment as well with two gateway workers and the gate manager on the APIM side. Then two IDS servers.

I'm trying to connect from my Windows device, so I'm not on the actual Linux server. Also, I have a secondary user store added and when I login to the store and publisher I use those credentials. I tried both my secondary user store credentials and the admin credentials both return same error.

What are some possible fixes I can do? Or I'm I off with some configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download a fresh installation of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Mars 2). Then added the plugins manually from http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/developer-studio-kernel/4.1.0/apim-tools/releases/2.0.0/ repo. I originally had the eclipse download from the wso2 website http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/. I thought that it had all the right plugins, but I guess there is something missing in it.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you have to use the WSO2 trust store in your Java Application. If the plugin doesn't allow you to pass the JVM args, you probably need to add them on the `eclipse.ini` file, located inside the Eclipse folder.

Assuming you didn't change the default settings, pass the following JVM parameters to and you're good to go.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path_to_wso2_apim>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=wso2carbon
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
```

If your Eclipse and the WSO2 installation are not int he same computer you just need to copy the wso2carbon.jks to your PC and update the location on the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` argument above.

Comment: I'm still unable to connect and get the same error. I do have my own keystore; added to both the APIM and the IDS. So would I some how have to add Developer Studio as a trusted user to them? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Developer Studio for WSO2 and I installed Spring Tool Suite 4 and followed the steps mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Installing+the+API+Manager+Tooling+Plug-In for APIM Tool and it solved the problem.